# Count number of rows with certain criteria that can appear in any column

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I need to return the count of rows that contain two criteria within a range of columns. The criteria can appear in any of 3 columns. For example:

```
 |  A           B           C
1|  external    FSO        
2|  FSO         internal    test
3|  test        AI          internal
4|  FSO         test        external
5|  AI          internal     
6|  FSO
7|  external    test        FSO
8|  external    test
```

If I needed to return the count all columns with `FSO` and `external`, I would return a count of 3 since they appear in rows 1,4, and 7.

How could I accomplish this? My original query does not work: `=COUNTIFS(Issues!$E$2:$I$500,”external”,Issues!$E$2:$I$500,”FSO”)`

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `filter()` with two conditions, like this:

```
=count( 
  iferror( 
    filter( 
      row(Issues!A1:C), 
      regexmatch(Issues!A1:A & Issues!B1:B & Issues!C1:C, "FSO"), 
      regexmatch(Issues!A1:A & Issues!B1:B & Issues!C1:C, "external") 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: I've been bashing my head against this for hours, and this solved it. Thanks a ton!